# Как поставить таймаут на асинхронную функцию?

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, timeout

У меня есть функция которая делает request и мне нужно прерывать ее если запрос идет слишком долго(допустим 5 сек).Пробовал через setTimeout setInterval, не получается

Comment: Попробуйте обрывать запрос используя [глобальные события](https://jquery-docs.ru/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Comment: А передать опцию `timeout : 5000` в `request` не подходит?

Comment: Через какую библиотеку запрос то отправляете?